# How to periodically trigger an time-lapse event every specific time interval

Tags: c#, loops, timer

I wanted to create a time-lapse control, for example, when the program starts, after time interval t1, trigger event A (e.g switch on), then wait after time interval t2, trigger event B (e.g.switch off), and this process will be executed periodically for n times.

What I have achieved so far is I could loop the two events only when t1=t2, I don't know how to make t1 and t2 two separate controllable variables.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private int counter; //counter to control the cycle times
        private int EventIndex;//control the event status

        private void InitializeTimer()
        {
            counter = 0;
            EventIndex = 0;
            timer1.Enabled = true; // Hook up timer's tick event handler.  
            this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        }

        //function for switch the event status

        private void UpdateEvent()
        {
            EventIndex = 1 - EventIndex;  // loop event index between 1 and 0

            if (EventIndex.Equals(1))
            {
                //Exceute command for event A
            }
            else 
            {
                //Exceute command for event A
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal t = numericUpDown1.Value; //time interval t between two events
            int interval = Convert.ToInt32(t);

            decimal n = numericUpDown2.Value; //periodically excute the process n times
            int cycle = Convert.ToInt32(n);

            //using the numeric input value to set up the interval time
            timer1.Interval = interval 


            if (counter >= cycle)  
            {
                // Exit loop code.  
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                counter = 0;

            }
            else
            {            
                UpdateEvent();
                counter = counter + 1;// Increment counter.
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Your description is unclear. Is event `B` must wait for an interval and trigger after `A` is fired?

Comment: @LouisGo Thanks, I made edits hopefully make it more clear, and yes I want event B to wait a specific time interval after event A triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have `UpdateEvent` set the timer interval after an event:

```
private void UpdateEvent()
{
    if (EventIndex.Equals(1))
    {
        timer1.Interval = //delay until event B;
    }
    else 
    {
        timer1.Interval = //delay until event A;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you make two timer for each event.

`timerA` is interval t1, trigger event A.
`timerB` is interval t2, trigger event B.

By seperating timer, you may not accidentally change your timer interval into unexpected reults.

```
 void UpdateEventA(){
     if( counter >= cycle ){
         timerA.Enable = false;
         return;
     }
     // A working
     timerA.Enable = false;
     timerB.Enable = true;
 }

 void UpdateEventB(){
     // B working
     timerB.Enable = falsed;
     timerA.Enable = true;
     counter ++;
 }
```

However if you have Event ABCDE and need to execute in sequence. I'll suggest you use one timer and calculate interval internally in single `Tick` event.